# What are the properties of the Objects of type FILE

Tags: c, file, properties, stdio

> FILE objects are usually created by a
>   call to either fopen or tmpfile, which
>   both return a reference to one of
>   these objects.

What are the attributes of the Struct named FILE, or is it platform dependent?

Comment: It's an opaque type. You are not meant to know. The only access is via the functions provided in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is it is platform dependent. At least using glibc on Linux, `FILE` is in fact a typedef from `_IO_FILE` which is implemented in `libio.h`:

```
struct _IO_FILE {
  int _flags;       /* High-order word is _IO_MAGIC; rest is flags. */
#define _IO_file_flags _flags

  /* The following pointers correspond to the C++ streambuf protocol. */
  /* Note:  Tk uses the _IO_read_ptr and _IO_read_end fields directly. */
  char* _IO_read_ptr;   /* Current read pointer */
  char* _IO_read_end;   /* End of get area. */
  char* _IO_read_base;  /* Start of putback+get area. */
  char* _IO_write_base; /* Start of put area. */
  char* _IO_write_ptr;  /* Current put pointer. */
  char* _IO_write_end;  /* End of put area. */
  char* _IO_buf_base;   /* Start of reserve area. */
  char* _IO_buf_end;    /* End of reserve area. */
  /* The following fields are used to support backing up and undo. */
  char *_IO_save_base; /* Pointer to start of non-current get area. */
  char *_IO_backup_base;  /* Pointer to first valid character of backup area */
  char *_IO_save_end; /* Pointer to end of non-current get area. */

  struct _IO_marker *_markers;

  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;

  int _fileno;
#if 0
  int _blksize;
#else
  int _flags2;
#endif
  _IO_off_t _old_offset; /* This used to be _offset but it's too small.  */

#define __HAVE_COLUMN /* temporary */
  /* 1+column number of pbase(); 0 is unknown. */
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];

  /*  char* _save_gptr;  char* _save_egptr; */

  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
#ifdef _IO_USE_OLD_IO_FILE
};
```

As Martin York says in his comments, you are not meant to know about the internals of this structure. This particular definition of the structure is not guaranteed to be the same across implementations; I'd expect MSVC's file structure to be different.

Answer (score 2):

`FILE` is a platform-dependent type, very probably a `struct`, that ultimately contains or points to at least:

1. two offsets into the file opened, one for reading, one for writing;
2. whether the file is opened for reading, for writing, or for both;
3. whether the file is opened for binary or text I/O;
4. EOF/error state of the stream;
5. a buffer;
6. a flag indicating block buffering or line buffering;
7. `char` or `wchar_t` orientation;
8. the last character put into the stream by `ungetc`.

If I'm not forgetting anything, this is all you can access with the `stdio` functions and those form the only interface for the use and inspection of `FILE` objects. Since `FILE` is opaque, you're not supposed to know *how* it keeps all this information.

POSIX in addition specifies that you can retrieve the underlying file descriptor with the `fileno` function/macro.

Comment: 5. a flag indicating block buffering, line buffering, or no buffering.

Comment: 7. the current shift state (for multibyte streams)

Comment: 8. the orientation of the stream, i.e. if it is a char or wide char stream.

Comment: 2. whether the file is opened for reading, writing, appending, or read/write; and whether it has been opened in text or binary mode.

Comment: @DevSolar: no buffering can be implemented with a `NULL` buffer. You're right about the rest.

Comment: @larsmans: Wrong. A call to `setvbuf()` with a NULL (second) argument will result in `setvbuf()` allocating the buffer itself. If you want "no buffering", you need to pass _IONBF as third parameter.

Comment: @DevSolar: ehm, except, is appending not the same as write with a different initial write offset?

Comment: @DevSolar: your remark about `setvbuf` describes the *interface* of buffering, but not necessarily the *implementation*.

Comment: @larsmans: Even for `_IONBF` you need an internal buffer, unless you want to make a system call for every character in e.g. a `puts()` call. In any case, what the *implementation* does with the contents of FILE is off-limits for the user in any case. And appending is specified to reset the offset *right before every write operation*. If the host OS doesn't support that on itself, it can be a major PITA to get *that* right in an userspace implementation...

Comment: @DevSolar: you're right about appending. However, since `puts` has a pointer to its input, it can write that out in a single system call. With scatter/gather I/O (`writev` and friends) it can also output the newline in the same call. 4.4BSD ("Torek stdio") does that.

Comment: @larsmans: OK, bad example. I *knew* I should have used `printf()` - you have to buffer *that* noteable's output somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

From draft [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) of the C Language Standard, § 7.19.1, paragraph 2:

> The types declared are `size_t` (described in 7.17);
>     `FILE`
> which is an object type capable of recording all the information needed to control a
> stream, including its file position indicator, a pointer to its associated buffer (if any), an
> *error indicator* that records whether a read/write error has occurred, and an *end-of-file* indicator that records whether the end of the file has been reached; and
>     `fpos_t`
> which is an object type other than an array type capable of recording all the information
> needed to specify uniquely every position within a file.

The exact contents of the FILE type are implementation-dependant, and are not meant to be accessed directly.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer - sorry about this.

FILE is a handle, not a structure. It's basically represents a lock on the file you are either reading or writing to.

I would suggest reading the help relating to the fopen call for example, there are plenty of on-line help.

Hope this assists.

Comment: FILE is a type, not a handle, and often is a typedef to a structure (due to the pointer - cf. with pthread_t for pointerless typedefs). It does not represent a lock either (stdio has no file locking), but a state of the file handle, comprising some system-dependent state (such as fd) and the stdio buffers at least.