# gdb - Interpreting output of print on FILE type

Tags: c, file, gdb

I am currently using `gdb` to debug a file. I have set a breakpoint at one of the file's methods, which takes in as arguments two `FILE` pointers. I ran a `print *filename1` on one of the passed in arguments (`filename1`). It outputted the following:

```
$4 = {_flags = -72540028, _IO_read_ptr = 0x0, _IO_read_end = 0x0, _IO_read_base = 0x0, 
  _IO_write_base = 0x0, _IO_write_ptr = 0x0, _IO_write_end = 0x0, _IO_buf_base = 0x0, 
  _IO_buf_end = 0x0, _IO_save_base = 0x0, _IO_backup_base = 0x0, _IO_save_end = 0x0, 
  _markers = 0x0, _chain = 0x7ffff7dd4340, _fileno = 1, _flags2 = 0, _old_offset = -1, 
  _cur_column = 0, _vtable_offset = 0 '\000', _shortbuf = "", _lock = 0x7ffff7dd5ab0, 
  _offset = -1, __pad1 = 0x0, __pad2 = 0x7ffff7dd4580, __pad3 = 0x0, __pad4 = 0x0, __pad5 = 0, 
  _mode = 0, _unused2 = '\000' <repeats 19 times>}
```

It should be noted that `print filename2` done on the other filename yields the following: `$1 = (FILE *) 0x7ffff7dd4340`

What I was wondering is how I can interpret these values? What is `_flags` and `_chain`? I haven't been able to find any big documentation on interpreting this output. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: These are all internal data used by `stdio`. To undertand them, you need to look at the stdio source code.

Comment: `_chain` is probably a pointer to another `FILE` structure in a linked list.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks for clarifying that `stdio` part. Is reading the source code the only way of going about this?

Comment: You might be able to figure out the important parts just by reading header files.

Comment: Find the header that defines the `FILE` typedef, it probably has a bunch of macros for the flags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the properties of the Objects of type FILE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862532/what-are-the-properties-of-the-objects-of-type-file)

Comment: I agree that it may be a duplicate, but there are some names here that do not seem to have an explanation in the other thread (e.g. _chain).