# How do I print out the contents of a file in hex using gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

I'm trying to build a program that resizes a bmp image by a factor of f, but having problems identifying what's going wrong with the program. I thought of using gdb to examine what is being read from the sourced image and written to the new image but when I try to print the contents of the final image it seems to be different than what i'd expect.

So, the program initially reads from the first image through a file pointer called `inptr`. The first 14 and 40 bytes from the first image are stored in a variable of type bitmapfileheader and bitmapinfoheader called `bf` and `bi` which are 14 and 40 bytes respectively.  The properties of these structs are altered to account for the change in size of the final image. The structs are then written to the new file through a pointer called `outptr`

After the structs are written to the new file I printed the contents of bf(in gdb) with the command

```
print bf
```

and prints out

```
{bfType = 19778, bfSize = 670, bfReserved1 = 0, bfReserved2 = 0, bfOffBits = 54}
```

Here is the same information when using the command `p/x bf` to format it in hex

```
{bfType = 0x4d42, bfSize = 0x29e, bfReserved1 = 0x0, bfReserved2 = 0x0, bfOffBits = 0x36}
```

The problem comes when  i try to print the contents of the new image. I used this command to print the first 14 bytes

```
`x /14xh outptr`
```

which prints

```
0x603250:       0x2c84  0xfbad  0x0000  0x0000  0x4000  0xf7ff  0x7fff  0x0000
0x603260:       0x4000  0xf7ff  0x7fff  0x0000  0x4000  0xf7ff
```

All of the bytes seem to be different from what was stored in `bf`. I was hoping to use the x command in gdb to print out something similar to what xxd does in the terminal, but I'm not sure why the contents of outptr are different than the `bf` struct.

Here is a link to the [source code](https://pastebin.com/xRuymKTd) and here is the [bmp.h](https://pastebin.com/5a6vkgk0) header file.

Comment: Related: [what are the properties of the objects of type FILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862532/what-are-the-properties-of-the-objects-of-type-file). It's possible that `x/14xh outptr->_IO_write_base` will show what you want, if the buffer still contains the data that is at the beginning the file.